# What's a word for "toughish"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, slang, pejorative-language, euphemisms

I am looking for an adjective that can be used to describe a 'thug'. Seeing that toughish isn't in most dictionaries (nor did I expect it to be, but an entry in a thesaurus would have been nice), nor do the synonyms of tough really do a 'thug' justice, I came to you guys for assistance.

I don't want to be too blunt and call him a thug, nor too mild by employing a euphenism, so i'm opting for the *-ish* form of a noun such as in "He was acting childish" etc., etc.  Only "He was acting thuggish" doesn't really quite make the cut.

Crude?  Too mild.
Violent?  Too harsh.
Uncultured?  Too way off the mark.

Honestly, I don't think I've ever encountered this much difficulty in choosing a word before.

If I don't get some killa ideas on here I'm gonna hafta gofer the good 'ol "He was actin all ghetto".

Comment: Why would you go for *tough-ish* and not just *tough*? What about *tough* as it relates to your usage made you want to add "*-ish*"?

Comment: What's wrong with **thuggish**? You don't say why you reject it. Are you looking for a word to modify the noun **thug**, so that **thuggish thug** wouldn't do?

Comment: How about *stern*?

Comment: Consider "rogue".

Answer (score 3):

**Brutish**

Resembling, befitting, or being typical of a brute [Webster's]

Comment: Can you cite which Webster edition it is? As I checked, it says "brute *or beast*". Did you omit that part?

Comment: Yes. It didn't seem necessary. But that's checkin' the facts!

Answer (score 1):

Brutish is good for ending in -ish. I'm not sure how much of a requirement that is. Here are a few that don't end in -ish that I think work really well for thugs (links go to Dictionary.com definitions):

1. [Pugnacious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pugnacious) - this is my favorite; a person who is ready to fight, it also reminds me of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29238/what-does-it-mean-to-describe-someones-chin-as-pugnacious).
2. [Bellicose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bellicose) - this means warlike; someone who is loud and blustering
3. [Belligerent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/belligerent) - another favorite; this is how I imagine I behave when I am aggressively drunk

All of the above focus on the thuggish-ness of thugs in the sense of people who are mainly muscle at the command of their leader. Otherwise, if you are set on -ish, then my last suggestion is

4. [Churlish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/churlish) - a mean person.

This word is more broadly applicable to the surly, narrow-minded, ill-natured aspect of thuggery. It would not apply to thugs with a sense of humor, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your sentence, I'd go with **confrontational** which is somewhere in the middle in that it can refer to both a physical or verbal altercation.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with plan B, [**gangster**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gangster?s=ts) is a bit more accessible than ghetto:

> **Synonyms**
>
> mobster, hoodlum, crook, thug; hood, goon.